# Optionals in Swift. Why this behavior?

Tags: swift

I think I understand how optionals work in Swift, but sometimes I fail to see the logic, and I can't derive it from the docs either, so I hope someone can help me here.

The issue is this:
I have a class declared as follows:

```
class Person {
    let firstName:String!
    let lastName:String!

    init(firstName:String!,lastName:String!) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

Next I instantiate the class and use it (code can be simplified but I just pulled what my app is doing without showing all the boilerplate around it, so please don't suggest me how to optimize this):

```
let myPerson = Person.init("First","Last")
var aSecondPerson:Person!

...
aSecondPerson = myPerson

let someString = "\(aSecondPerson.firstName) \(aSecondPerson.lastName)"
```

Now I would assume the contents of `someString` to be `First Last` but instead it is: `Optional("First") Optional("Last")`

Why is it still considering the values as optional considering the amount of `!` used all over the place?

Comment: Also, this isn't Java, you don't say `let myPerson = new Person("First","Last")` ;)

Comment: Yeah, i've works with the same issue... Something strange, have you tried to remove the `!` at the declaration ? Or maybe set the var like this `let firstName = ""`

Comment: @JimmyJames: Using an empty String to represent the absence of value is highly discouraged. And I agree with you,  we should also avoid a code full of `!` but this is off topic in this thread.

Comment: @appzYourLife: thanks, i didn't know that !! Now I know it :)

Comment: @Hamish I just corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. Didn't find it myself.